# Seeking free tile server like mapbox studio?

Tags: tiles, software-recommendations, vector-tiles

Is there any free tile service/server like mapbox studio so that I can upload my .shp files and it will work like it does in mapbox studio tiles and get geojson tiles on Leaflet.js map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use mapbox tippecanoe or GDAL Ogr2OGR to create your mbtiles vector tiles. There are tons of tile servers tile strata,tileserver-gl,tileserver-php,any language you want python, Go,nodejs,php